# How to integrate firestore in UWP app for RaspberryPi running Win10 IOT Core?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, raspberry-pi, arm, grpc

I need to add the Firebase's firestore functionality to my app (background UWP app) that runs on a raspberry (ARM) running Windows 10 IOT Core.

I managed to make the app fully work (with firestore in it) on my PC and deploy it on the raspberry but I get an error when the app starts:

```
Error: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: path1 
    at System.IO.Path.Combine(String, String) + 0x2c
    at Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeExtension.LoadUnmanagedLibrary() + 0x36
    at Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeExtension.LoadNativeMethods() + 0x28
    at Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeExtension..ctor() + 0x12
    at Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeExtension.Get() + 0x4a
    at Grpc.Core.GrpcEnvironment.GrpcNativeInit() + 0x48
    at Grpc.Core.GrpcEnvironment..ctor() + 0x64
    at Grpc.Core.GrpcEnvironment.AddRef() + 0x54
    at Grpc.Core.Channel..ctor(String, ChannelCredentials, IEnumerable`1) + 0xa8
    at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.GrpcCore.GrpcCoreAdapter.CreateChannelImpl(String, ChannelCredentials, GrpcChannelOptions) + 0x24
    at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.GrpcAdapter.CreateChannel(String, ChannelCredentials, GrpcChannelOptions) + 0x16
    at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ChannelPool.GetChannel(GrpcAdapter, String, GrpcChannelOptions, ChannelCredentials) + 0x58
    at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ChannelPool.GetChannel(GrpcAdapter, String, GrpcChannelOptions) + 0x1a8
    at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ClientBuilderBase`1.CreateCallInvoker() + 0x5e
    at Google.Cloud.Firestore.V1.FirestoreClientBuilder.BuildImpl() + 0x16
    at Google.Cloud.Firestore.FirestoreDbBuilder.Build() + 0x1ee
    at Google.Cloud.Firestore.FirestoreDb.Create(String, FirestoreClient) + 0x1bc
    at Processing.Service.Firestore.<Initialize>d__22.MoveNext() + 0xc4
```

I tried unchecking the "Compile with .net Native tool chain" project option but now I get the following error:

```
Error loading native library "C:\Data\Programs\WindowsApps\Service_1.1.94.0_arm\grpc_csharp_ext.x86.dll".
    at Grpc.Core.Internal.UnmanagedLibrary..ctor(String[] libraryPathAlternatives)
    at Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeExtension.LoadUnmanagedLibrary()
    at Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeExtension.LoadNativeMethods()
    ...
    at Google.Cloud.Firestore.V1.FirestoreClientBuilder.BuildImpl()
    at Google.Cloud.Firestore.FirestoreDbBuilder.Build()
    at Google.Cloud.Firestore.FirestoreDb.Create(String projectId, FirestoreClient client)
```

On both situations I got 224 warnings like:

```
    ILTransform : warning ILT0028: Found native library 'W:\Service\obj\ARM\Release\ilc\in\grpc_csharp_ext.x64.dll' with unexpected CPU architecture 'amd64', while the current build target architecture is set to 'arm'. Your application may fail to launch. Please make sure to build your application with the matching CPU architecture.  Service         
    ILTransform : warning ILT0028: Found native library 'W:\Service\obj\ARM\Release\ilc\in\grpc_csharp_ext.x86.dll' with unexpected CPU architecture 'x86', while the current build target architecture is set to 'arm'. Your application may fail to launch. Please make sure to build your application with the matching CPU architecture.    Service         
    MCG : warning MCG0007: Unresolved P/Invoke method 'grpc_csharp_ext!gprsharp_convert_clock_type' for method 'Grpc.Core.Internal.Timespec     Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeMethods.DllImportsFromSharedLib.gprsharp_convert_clock_type(Grpc.Core.Internal.Timespec, Grpc.Core.Internal.ClockType)'. Calling this method would throw exception at runtime. Please make sure the P/Invoke either points to a Windows API allowed in UWP applications, or a native DLL that is part of the package. If for some reason your P/Invoke does not satisfy those requirements, please use [DllImport(ExactSpelling=true) to indicate that you understand the implications of using non-UWP APIs.  Service         
    MCG : warning MCG0007: Unresolved P/Invoke method 'grpc_csharp_ext!gprsharp_free' for method 'System.Void Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeMethods.DllImportsFromSharedLib.gprsharp_free(System.IntPtr)'.                                                                                         Calling this method would throw exception at runtime. Please make sure the P/Invoke either points to a Windows API allowed in UWP applications, or a native DLL that is part of the package. If for some reason your P/Invoke does not satisfy those requirements, please use [DllImport(ExactSpelling=true) to indicate that you understand the implications of using non-UWP APIs.  Service
```

Notes:

- The json config file and the environment variable required are present on the device.
- I deploy on the device using "App package" (*.appxbundle)
- I'm using Windows 10 IOT Core and UWP application because the is the first way I succeeded to make the app work on the raspberry, I'm open to changing that if the code stays in C#.
- Found a tutorial (https://dev.to/erikest/grpc-on-dotnet-core-preview3-on-raspberrypi-3-4nf4) to rebuild "grpc_csharp_ext.x86" for ARM but it give a ".so" file, not a ".dll".

I tried:

- Adding "LibGrpc.Arm" & "libgrpc_csharp_ext.arm7" nugets to the project.
- Updating "Google.Cloud.Firestore" nuget to "v2.3.0-beta1"

Ideas:

- Rebuild GRPC for ARM (would it produce dll files?)
- Using another Firestore nuget (ie: Xamarin) instead of Google.Cloud.Firestore
- Using another Firebase SDK (ie: Web or Unity)
- Run this C# service on raspbian (if it is possible) instead of Win 10  IOT Core (Tried, same error...)
- Use Firebase RPC API directly

I need advice, suggestions, ideas guys... If anyone can help, that would be awesome!! :-)

Thank you

Comment: As the Firebase application is working on your PC, would you say that the problem relies more with the other technologies you are using?

Comment: @MrTech I believe that the fact that the Raspberry runs on a ARM processor is what's causing the issue... But how could I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to use Grpc.Core on an ARM-based platform. Grpc.Core internally relies on a native library (grpc_csharp_ext) and the Grpc.Core package doesn't come with an ARM-build version of that library out of the box - so what you are trying to do will not work.

What you can do:

- try using grpc-dotnet (Grpc.Net.Client, https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet) which doesn't have a native component and thus should work fine even on an ARM-based raspberry.
- you can try to compile grpc_csharp_ext yourself to target ARM and while that's totally feasible, it's quite involved so I wouldn't recommend going that route.